# Azure Active Directory B2C Catching Error from Invitation Page

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

We have a custom invitation flow, which receives a JWT in the `id_token_hint` parameter and extracts an email address from it.
That JWT has an expiry, and when a user clicks on an expired link, he is redirected to the login page.
Instead of redirecting the user to a login page, I want to intercept the error code that is returned from the invitation page in my application (using MSAL.js) and display an error message.
But the only form of "error code" that my application receives from the invitation page, is this:

AADB2C90208: The provided id_token_hint parameter is expired. Please provide another token and try again.
Correlation ID: e49dbe44-fc02-4379-86e5-12a1347d5cc3
Timestamp: 2019-08-27 08:00:53Z

In the local storage.

Now, my guess is that I rely on the code `AADB2C90208` to know that I was redirected due to invalid token, but I have some doubts.

1. I can't find anything about that particular status code (`AADB2C90208`)
2. The error message is in plain text, I have to extract the code with some kind of string expression, which makes me think that this is not what Microsoft had intended.

What do you think?

Answer (score 2):

When an error code is specific, dependency can be taken on the error code. There are plans from AADB2C to publish the error codes soon.

you can use this sample code to see how to user error codes
https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-dotnet-webapp-and-webapi/blob/master/TaskWebApp/App_Start/Startup.Auth.cs#L87

**Update**

The error codes are documented here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/error-codes

For this specific case -

> AADB2C90208   The provided id_token_hint parameter is expired. Please
>   provide another token and try again.

Comment: So in my case, is the error code (`AADB2C90208`) considered specific even though it's not documented by AADB2C?

Comment: Tricky question :). There are generic error codes like AADB2C90085 which cant be taken dependency on because the message says that an internal error occurred, In this case, the message is specific. In any case, only a documentation will ensure that  error code is supported. As of now I believe its safe to take dependency on this error code.

Comment: I think that I will use that code then :) Another thing, in the example that you sent (the c# one), I tried to replicate the same behavior with the MSAL.js library by trying to catch the erorr in the `authCallback` function (https://carbon.now.sh/6MFHcIiiJtqIHi0SiUKd), but it didn't work. that error doesn't trigger the callback. Is extacting in from local storage the only way?

Comment: The code in this sample should help you finding the error - https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-javascript-msal-singlepageapp.